# Assumptions on the target density in the RWM optimal scaling paper by Roberts, Gelman and Gilks

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

In the famous paper [Weak Convergence and Optimal Scaling of Random Walk Metropolis Algorithms](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/theory7.pdf) by Roberts, Gelman and Gilks, at the bottom of page 116, the supremum of the third derivative of $\ln f$ is occuring on the right-hand side of a bound. However, the assumptions on $f$ don't seem to ensure that this supremum is finite.

Am I missing something? The finiteness seems to be crucial for the conclusion.

EDIT: Just noticed that he's assuming that $f$ is only $C^2$. So, $(\ln f)'''$ does not even need to exist ...